# How to move issue to sprint in Youtrack

Tags: youtrack

I have started using youtrack, I have created a project and an issue within the project.

Then I have created an agile board and I wanted yo have the issue on the "open" column, but I can't seem to be able to do this, all I found was a way to create *new* cards

I would appreciate help with this problem, I do not want to recreate my issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option would be to use a command on an issue view or issue list:

[image]

The other one is to open a backlog on the board and pick up an issue from there:

[image]

There are also plenty of configuration options to make issues appear on board automatically. Make sure to consult the [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2017.1/Plan-a-sprint.html) on how to configure that for your particular development work flow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried the second option and I can not see my issue on the board. I am displayed a message "1 unresolved issue not visible on the board"

Comment: "1 unresolved issue not visible on the board" - that means issue state  doesn't match agile board column set. E.g. you have "Open", "In progress" and "Fixed" columns, while the issue is "Submitted". The fix would be to either reconfigure columns or update the issue to fit one of the columns.

Comment: @Jk1 A `sprint {sprint name}` command would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Kanban board, and do not see the `Board` command. Hence, you can follow the second option suggested by @Jk1. This will maintain the same copy of the story on both boards.

In order to remove the issue from the old board, go to the issue, and in the commands you can add `remove Board <name of the board>`

[image]